# What is a way to add the values of a list to the values of another list by the index of a third list and output one of the first two lists?

Tags: python, indexing, sum

Let's say I have three lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 3, 4]
list3 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to write some code that outputs:

```
outputlist = [4, 3, 4, 0]
```

Where the value of the an item in list1 dictates the positional value* of the item in list3 to which the value of the item in list2 with the same index as the item in the first list is added. That's a mouthful, let me provide an example:

*(NOTE: if the value of an item in list1 is n the index in list3 I want it to denote is (n-1))

list1[2] = 3. Therefore the value list2[2] ( = 4) must be added to the value list3[3] ( = 0) and output into outputlist as outputlist[3] = 0 + 4 = 4

I hope this is clear enough to explain what I am trying to get at.

Currently I am zipping a counter.Collections function

```
counted_numbers = counter.Collections(list_of_numbers)
print(counted_numbers)
```

output:

```
Counter({number: frequency}, {number: frequency}, ...)
```

and, by using the code:

```
counteds = list(sorted(collections.Counter(list_of_numbers).items()))
numbers, theirFrequency = list(zip(*counteds))
```

python makes two separate lists, numbers and theirFrequency, containing the numbers and their frequency with corresponding indexes, which is great. numbers and Theirfrequency are essentially in the form of list1 and list2 respectively.

So to repeat the question now with all this context, how can I sum the value of items in list2 to the values in list3 whose indexes correspond to the values of the items in list1 whose indexes correspond to the indexes of the items in list2?

So that if there is NO item 4 (i.e. index 3) in list1 nor in list2, the code still outputs a zero for the 4th item (3rd index) in outputlist, with all the rest of the indexes added?

By the way, the summing function is crucial to the rest of my code - so the item in list2 must be added to the item in list3 and should NOT be replacing the item in list3.

Thanks.

Comment: does this help  `res = [list2[i-1]+list3[i] for  i in list1]` though it is considering all list of same size

Comment: ```for i in range(len(list1)): l1 = list1[i]; l2 = list2[i]; list3[l1-1] += l2```. As noted, you want to assign to ```list3``` index as ```n-1``` from value of ```list1```.

Comment: @sahasrara62 yep, sadly "list index out of range". Thanks for your suggestion, though!

Comment: you can do this with list comprehension, but you need to see how you are adding with index and what happen when  there is difference in list length

Comment: @sahasrara62 I will try another day to see if I can make the same thing work using list comprehension.

Comment: does it have to be list comprehensions?

Comment: For ```list comprehesion```, you might want to try this: ```print([list3[list1[i]-1] + list2[i] if i < len(list1) else list3[i] for i in range(len(list3))])```